# why is that $H_{k-1/2}-H_k = 2H_{2k}-H_k$?

Tags: harmonic-numbers

In "Concrete Mathematics", question number 7.10 involves the factor $H_{k-1/2}-H_k$, which when I look at the answer, it states that the identities is valid:
$$
\begin{align}
H_{k-1/2}-H_k &= \frac{2}{2k-1}+\cdots+\frac{2}{1} \\
&= 2H_{2k}-H_k
\end{align}
$$
which the first line comes from:
$$
\begin{align}
H_{k-1/2} - H_{-1/2} &= \frac{1}{k-1/2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1/2} \\
&= \frac{2}{2k-1}+\cdots+\frac{2}{1} \\
\end{align}
$$

But, isn't $\frac{2}{2k-1}+\cdots+\frac{2}{1} = 2\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\cdots+1\right)=2H_{2k-1}$?

Apparently, $2H_{2k}-H_k$ is not equal to $2H_{2k-1}$. I can't find out where I have done wrong.

Comment: You might become less confused if you write summations instead of relying on $\cdots$.

Comment: I think the what you are thinking as $H_{2k-1}$ is not that. It only contains odd numbers. You can add all the even terms and subtract them and manipulate to get final answer.

Comment: $H_{n-1/2}=2H_{2n}-H_n-2\ln(2)$